# Operation research - postoptimality analysis - find all solutions to problem

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, linear-programming, operations-research

I'm currently learning Operations Research from "Introduction to Operations Research - Hillier". I know that somethimes a problem has many optimal solutions. For example in a two dimensional problem the set of solutions could be all points on a line with ends optimal CPF solutions ($s =\lambda_{1} x_{1} + \lambda_{2} x_{2} $ , where $\lambda_{1} + \lambda_{2} =1$) . For a three dimensional problem a plane, or a line and so on.

My question is how can I find all the solutions to a problem in the postoptimality analysis after I have found an optimal solution (looking at the last tableau / the last iteration)?

I am attaching a picture of a tablue from the textbook, because I guide myself by it and I know that there are different forms of the method being used sometimes.[image]

I think this problem has only one optimal solution, but if another had more than one how could I find them. An example with a good explanation would be great.

Comment: It seems, that this problem has only one optimal solution ($x_i$-combination). In the last (optimal) tableau there is no coefficient (non-basic variable) of the objective function with value 0. This is the assumption to get another optimal solution with $z^*=36$. Thus you are right.

Comment: I wasn't asking about this problem , but how to find the other solutions in general ( for some problem having them). How can I find the other solutions after looking that there are non-basic variables with coeficients 0 in the objective function? If you could write a more detailed explanation with an example maybe, I could give accept it as the answer.

Comment: Also I don't know what happens when the coefficient of a  variable in the objective function has negative value and all the coefficients in the same column are also negative. Does the simplex method stop, or do we have no optimul solution ?

Comment: @calculus Thanks for the info I just found out how to get the other solutions from your info, it turns out I just had to do some iterations with the variable with a zero coeficient in the objective function as an entering basic variable. Thank you for that. Also my second question still remains.

Comment: To answer your second question of your comments. This case cannot happen. If your simplex tableau has been constructed correctly, you would have a solution at the beginning. In your example it is the tableau of Iteration 0. The solution is $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)=(0,0,4,12,18)$. The simplex tableau must contain slack variables and/or artificial variables. In the most cases it is not optimal. From this point your described situation will never happen after some iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the simplex method has found an optimal value, then what you are asking is for the existence of *[degenerate](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-053-optimization-methods-in-management-science-spring-2013/tutorials/MIT15_053S13_tut07.pdf)* solutions. As @calculus said, this will be indicated by one or more non-basic variables having a zero coefficient in the objective function formula (indicating that you could technically pivot to that variable and still have an optimal solution).